# How do correctly assign and useContext in Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-context

I have written a very simple sandbox to try to better understand useContext in Typescript. Im getting some strange errors but it still seems to work.

https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-usereducer-nygts?file=/src/App.tsx

```
import { useEffect, useReducer, createContext, useContext } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

let AppContext = createContext(undefined);

type AppState = {
  value: number;
};

type Action = {
  type: string;
};

const initialState = {
  value: 0
};

const reducer = (state: AppState, action: Action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "INCREMENT":
      state = { value: state.value + 1 };
      return state;

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

function Subscribe() {
  const { state } = useContext(AppContext);
  console.log("state", state);

  return (
    <>
      <p>subscriber</p>
      <p>state = {state.value}</p>
    </>
  );
}

export default function MyApp() {
  let [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({ type: "INCREMENT" });
  }, []);

  console.log("TodoApp.state", state);
  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{ state }}>
      <Subscribe />
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

I have an error on AppContextProvider.value:

```
Type '{ state: AppState; }' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(335, 9): The expected type comes from property 'value' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ProviderProps<undefined>'
```

and another on the useContext assignment: const { state } = useContext(AppContext);

```
Property 'state' does not exist on type 'undefined'.
```

I am clearly passing state to the subscriber and its updating so unsure why ts is complaining nor how to remedy it. Any advice is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify any context type. You can do something like this:

```
type AppContextType = {
   state: AppState
}
const AppContext = createContext<AppContextType|null>(null);
```